# Cannot find wireless driver for HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have an HP laptop (model: dv7-1267cl, Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium) and I cannot find the wireless driver for the laptop. I am need of a different version because my wireless connection under Windows is flaky and unreliable. I have problems printing to my wireless printer and logging in to and using several sites like reddit.com, phoenix.edu and facebook.com - I get several "page cannot be displayed" messages while using my wireless connection. I disable my wireless adapter and use an ethernet cable and it all works fine. I also used an Ubuntu Live CD to confirm that there is not a problem with the hardware. This is software/driver issue.

The drivers were auto installed by the OS. The Device Manager shows the wireless adapter as Atheros AR5009 802.11 a/g/n WiFi Adapter.

[image: Device Manager]

I have checked the HP website for my laptop and they do not have wireless drivers listed for that model wireless adapter. I have also checked with atheros.com and I do not see my model adapter on their list of available hardware.

Device Manager lists the Hardware ID's for my adapter as:

- PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002A&SUBSYS_1381103C&REV_01
- PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002A&SUBSYS_1381103C
- PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002A&CC_028000
- PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002A&CC_0280

A search for the first Hardware ID turned up [this question](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/Windows_Vista/Q_24040396.html) from experts-exchange.com. tl;dr A driver does not exist for that model adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I got in a support chat with HP and it looks like this driver solved my problem. It does not say in the page details that my card was supported but appears to work - I was able to use my printer. http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/genericSoftwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&softwareitem=ob-76373-1&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN+

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the answer. Maybe the tool DriverMax could also have helped.
http://download.cnet.com/DriverMax/3000-18513_4-10572602.html

At least for my HP Pavillion it was able to detect the hardware and download all the drivers.